# Crystal Reports - Select Current YYMM

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a Crystal Report that reads data from an access table.  I have a particular field in the access table called REPT_YYMM.  This is basically a run data field, so each month when a program is run it populates the current year/month in the field before exporting to access, so there is a way to do month to month comparisons.  For the report I'm working on I just want to display the data along with the current REPT_YYMM field when the data is refreshed on a monthly basis.  Is there a way to do this in a formula.  I'm not familiar enough with date type functions to know where to start.

Any guidance or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: what's the field type? YYMM isn't a standard date-time format, so I'm guessing it's probably a varchar or int?

Comment: The field is actually stored as text.  The field is generated in a SAS program as a character field but is then exported to access and becomes text.  I can surely change the date-time format to an acceptable format to work with Crystal.

Comment: Crystal will accept native date/time values from the underlying database (or rather, from ODBC). Once you've got a real datetime value, you can use the regular date field formatting options to display the YYMM format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if i understood correct you just need to filter the data where field REPT_YYMM = YYMM.

Goto selection formulas, record and enter:

```
{table.REPT_YYMM} = cStr(currentdate,'yyMM');
```

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear.  Even though I was not your suggestion was just what I was looking for.  Thank you!